# Replacing Mac OSX with Linux Distro, or FreeBSD

Tags: linux, freebsd, macintosh

I have a Macbook Pro 8,2 and really want to make the switch to something a little less stubborn and a little more flexible than the proprietary Mac OS X. I am a bit frustrated with MacPorts lately and Homebrew. I also would like to make the transition to a tiling window manager such as Awesome, RatPoison, or Xmonad. In the past I have had problems getting the Mac's wireless card working as well as setting up the EFI installer to boot to GRUB or LILO. So, I am curious if anyone here has had any experiences with running a Linux Distro like Slackware, Archlinux, Debian or a Unix OS such as FreeBSD on their MacBook Pro.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/about), not a discussion forum. “I am curious if anyone has had any experience” is not a question, it is a discussion starter, which is explicitly discouraged in the [FAQ#dontask]. Feel free to ask here if you have some specific problem you want help solving.

Answer (score 4):

I found the most compatible distro's for my Macbook pro's (9,1 and 10,1) tend to be Ubuntu and Fedora.

The Xorg drivers for the Macbook touchpad kinda suck, but I haven't messed with that stuff for a couple of years now.

Fedora tends to have lots of guides readily available for installs to a Mac.

Fedora has out of the box support for EFI systems. So no need for weird MBR voodoo. If you still have trouble with EFI with Fedora 17 or similar, take a look @ [rEFit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) for making booting an MBR possible.